# Switching from an open Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu to a different dropdown menu requires an extra tap on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

When a bootstrap dropdown is open, opening another dropdown requires two taps. This is because of an overlaying div that swallows all other input in order to close the first dropdown.

This is a known bug. According to the bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-usage):

> On mobile devices, opening a dropdown adds a .dropdown-backdrop as a
>   tap area for closing dropdown menus when tapping outside the menu, a
>   requirement for proper iOS support. This means that switching from an
>   open dropdown menu to a different dropdown menu requires an extra tap
>   on mobile.

However, the behaviour is not consistent. The backdrop overlay is **not** applied to dropdowns within a `.navbar-nav`, and as far as I can tell, everything appears to work just fine for me on my iPhone (Safari).

Check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzohjv1a/2) to see the different behaviours.

Does anyone know more about the iOS-specific issue that this is supposed to be for, and does anyone have a browser-compatible workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is due to "click" events not bubbling up to the body properly in iOS Safari, which would make Bootstrap unable to listen for dismiss clicks with one global handler. It appears that a different workaround has been added for Bootstrap 4 so that a backdrop is no longer required:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/22426

Answer (score 1):

I've posted some potential solutions in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzohjv1a/1).

1) Hiding the backdrop

```
.dropdown-backdrop {
    display: none;
}
```

2) Applying `.navbar-nav` to the dropdowns (and removing the negative margins).

Working on Windows (Chrome) and iPhone (Safari). Not tested any more than that. Does anyone know any issues with these approaches? It seems too easy...